# Стиль для ::before заходит на текст, как это исправить?

Tags: html, css, frontend

```css
.menu_item {
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
 overflow: hidden;
 color: #525252;
 font-weight: 600;
 font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
 cursor: pointer;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 2
}

.menu_item::before {
 content: "";
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #525252;
 border: 0.1px solid #525252;
 border-top-right-radius: 10px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
 left: -100%;
 transition: 0.5s;
}

.menu_item:hover::before {
 transition: 0.5s;
  color: #b3b3b3;
 left: 0%;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="menu_item">home</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.menu_item {
  z-index: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #525252;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2
}

.menu_item::before {
  z-index: -1;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #525252;
  border: 0.1px solid #525252;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  left: -100%;
  transition: left 0.5s;
}

.menu_item:hover::before {
  transition: 0.5s;
  color: #b3b3b3;
  left: 0%;
}

.menu_item:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="menu_item">home</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно добавить свойство z-index псевдоэлементу

```
.menu_item::before {
z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Это не работает